# How to access list from prolog Knowledge base

Tags: prolog

this is the element in my knowledge base, (exactly like this):

```
  DataBase = [book('A',[author('B','C')],154,12,6,[publishedYear(1990)]),
  book('Z',[author('Y','X')],155,1,62,[publishedYear(2009)])].
```

It is in the same pl-file with our other predicates.
How am I able to acces it?
for example if I want to do:

```
  ?- write(DataBase).
```

It gives an error, because apparantly it can't access the variable.

edit: the error I get is that it is a singleton variable:

```
   Singleton variables: [DB]
```

and:

```
   No permission to modify static_procedure `(=)/2'
```

Comment: please include *verbatim* copy of relevant portions of your pl file, your REPL interactions, and the error message.

Comment: this literally is my whole pl file. the error states that it is a singleton variable. For example, If I want to ?- write(DB), it can't acces it, even if I make a function in the knowledge base itself that uses this variable.

Answer (score 1):

(First of all, what you call "function" should be called "predicate")

If I understand correctly what you think you did, you wrote

```
Var = Something.
```

And then tried to "access" that variable in your predicate. You should note that a "variable" in logic programming is not the same as a "variable" in other programming paradigms.

In C, for example, a variable is a place where you can put information that you can later change. In logic programming, a variable is there to be **unified**, it is a variable in the mathematical sense.

You should also note that variables are *implicitly universally quantified*, so when you write

```
predicate(X,Y).
```

You are actually writing

```
forall X, forall Y, predicate(X,Y).
```

This means that *outside* of that predicate, if you use the string "X" again to name a variable, it is no longer the same one. Meaning, in the following

```
pred1(X).
pred2(X).
```

These are not the same variable.

What you can do to achieve what you seem to aim at is, for example:

```
database([book('A',[author('B','C')],154,12,6,[publishedYear(1990)]),
          book('Z',[author('Y','X')],155,1,62,[publishedYear(2009)])]).
```

and, if you want to use it in a predicate `pred`:

```
pred :- database(DB), do_this_with_it(DB).
```

But I might be wrong in understanding what you meant, so please do say if it doesn't answer your question.